# Onde esta o erro ? não consigo puxar tabela do banco de dados!

Tags: php, mysql

```
 function getUserAccessRoleByID($id)
{
    global $conn;

    $query = "select user_role from tbl_user_role where  id = ".$id;

    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);

    return $row['user_role'];
}



function get_Pessoas()
{
    global $conn;

    $query = "select * from pessoas where id "; //query the db

    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $resArr = array(); //create the result array

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) { //loop the rows returned from db
    $resArr[] = $row; //add row to array
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($resArr); echo '</pre>';
return $resArr;   
}

  aqui puxo os resultados 

   <?php 

     $pessoas = get_Pessoas(); //get the result array

                    foreach($pessoas as $cond) { //loop the array
                        echo '<h1>'. $cond['cd_name']. '</h1>';
                        echo '<p>'. $cond['cd_idade']. '</p>';
                    }

                     ?>
```

Comment: `select * from pessoas where id `. Qual id ?

Comment: Faça assim, retorna os erros de query: `$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: select * from pessoas where id referesr a id da tabela pessoas --:id --:nome --:telefone

Comment: Mas dá algum erro? Se sim, qual erro? E em que linha?

Comment: Não da erro em linha mas toda a pagina fica em branco como se não tivesse carregando nada ou puxão nada .. os erros não retornam

Comment: Não seria `$query = "select user_role from tbl_user_role where  id = '$id'";` ? Outra coisa já comentada é `where id` Acredito que deva ser `$query = "select * from pessoas"`; para trazer todas as linhas.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assoc() in /var/www/server/

Comment: As funções `mysql_*` estão obsoletas e foram removidas no PHP 7, o que provavelmente quer é `mysqli_fetch_assoc` com o `i`

Comment: Obrigado  o erro estava aqui mesmo mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) o erro estava aqui mesmo !